# Vendor Return Authorization Workflow Not Changing Approval Status (NetSuite)

Tags: workflow, netsuite

Vendor Return authorization is not getting approved through workflow.
Approval status field is set to approved in the final state of my workflow but still the main status of the transaction shows PENDING APPROVAL and the blue colored APPROVE RETURN button appears.
Can anyone advise what is needed to be done to do automatic approval through workflow, below is the screenshot of my Workflow.
[image]

Comment: Need a picture of the workflow to help. **Be sure to remove any and all information you do not want public if you post one.**

Comment: i have just uploaded my workflow's final state screenshot. Hope this helps u in helping me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the transition of workflow from "Pending Approval" state to "Approved" state we need to be sure that the transition to approved state happens on a click on a button i.e. Execute on button "Approve". Also, when you click on the transition arrow, you will see (1) condition and (2) "Transition on" options. Having wrong values there can stop the transition. For eg. for "transition on" if you have "After record submit, it will only work on record edit and if it's on entry then it will work when workflow enters new state and if nothing is selected like my screenshot then it will work for all events

[image: Condition and transition on options] Please see image for your reference [image: Available transitions]

Comment: @AnuradhaSinha - thank u for explaining this very clearly but I have already checked and have done this correctly. I am just not able to find the field that will turn the status of Vendor return authorization to PENDING RETURN in the last state.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'order status' in lieu of 'approval status'.

What status did you use for the rejected field?